# Why would Angular push index 0 array into a sub array and not index 1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have the following Array setup in my oninit:

```js
 this.tests = [{
      status: 0,
      testresults: [{       
        name: 'test',
          id: 1
      }]
    }
    ]
    ;

    this.tests.push([{
      status: 1,
      testresults: [{       
        name: 'test2',
          id: 2
      }]
    }
    ]
    }]);
```

This array works as expected. My goal is to push a queries results into the testresults array that is inside tests.

```
  this.tests[0].testresults.push(this.qryresults);
  this.tests[1].testresults.push(this.qryresults);
```

Index 0 works correctly, Index 1 gives back the following error:

```
"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing an array the second time around instead of an extra object, which results an error because the array you've pushed does not have the property `testresults`. Please refer to the code snippet below for a working revision of the code:

```js
(function() {
  this.qryresults = "some test data"
  this.tests = [{
    status: 0,
    testresults: [{
      name: 'test',
      id: 1
    }]
  }];

  this.tests.push({ // <--- removed [ here
    status: 1,
    testresults: [{
      name: 'test2',
      id: 2
    }]
  });              // <--- removed ] here

  this.tests[0].testresults.push(this.qryresults);
  this.tests[1].testresults.push(this.qryresults);
  console.log(this.tests)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You push array to array. So that, you must add object to array as :

```
this.tests.push({
  status: 1,
  testresults: [{       
    name: 'test2',
      id: 2
  }]
```

});

Comment: My code works above -- my questions is on the lines of code with indexes.

  this.tests[0].testresults.push(this.qryresults);
  this.tests[1].testresults.push(this.qryresults);

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can fix this issue following code;

```
tests = [{
    status: 0,
    testresults: [{
        name: 'test',
        id: 1
    }]
}];

qryresults = [{
    status: 1,
    testresults: [{
        name: 'test2',
        id: 2
    }]
}]

tests.push(...qryresults);
```